# Adding External Scripts to one Magento page

Tags: php, jquery, magento, fancybox

I have read up on this a bit, but still must be missing something.

I have a photo gallery page, and am using fancy box to show larger versions of the images on click. There are two scripts I need to add for fancybox, a jquery and fancybox script.

I have gone into the gallery xml page, and added this code into it so that it looks like this:

```
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <type>jquery_js</type>
            <script>http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js</script>
        </action>
        <action method="addJs">
            <type>fancybox_js</type>
            <script>/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js</script>
        </action>

    </reference>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
```

...

but then I don't know how to use them in my view. When I go to the page, I am still getting 404 errors for these scripts. I am probably missing some simple things as I've never tackled a magento issue before.

Thanks in advance, 
Alyssa

Comment: And without the type tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call an external file in Magento layout XML you can add a block

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="jquery.cdn.whatever.you.want.to.call.it">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>]]></text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

For your local fancybox file, (I presume it's locally hosted?), it depends where you saved it, there's a root js folder, so if it's in there you can use:

```
<action method="addJs">
    <script>fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js</script>
</action>
```

You don't need to a add `<type>` as addJs already defines it as a JS type and `fancybox_js` isn't an option as far as I'm aware for the  attribute, also note there's no / at the start, the script tag will add the path itself with a trailing slash.

If it's inside your theme folder you can use:

```
<action method="addJs">
    <type>skin_js</type>
    <script>fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js</script>
</action>
```

This will look in your theme js folder for a referred file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Your answer also helped me to realize I'd been trying to add the actions to the wrong xml file.

All the best and thanks again,